# Access UNION query to combine multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

**Situation:** The Access database I'm working on separates parts into left and right parts. The same part can be used on both sides. I am trying to create a query to count the total number of individual parts needed per piece.

**Question:** How do I create a query that allows to UNION multiple fields as shown below?

**Example:**

```
Table 1:
Part # |Left Part | Left Part Qty | Right Part | Right Part Quantity
1        xyz         5               xyz          7
2        abc         8               lmn          4

Table 2:
Part # | Needed
1        10
2        25

Query:
Part | Quantity
xyz    120 ((5 + 7) * 10)
abc    200 (8 * 25) 
lmn    100 (4 * 25)
```

**Edit:** My apologies but I forgot to add a part. I hadn't realized I needed to multiply with a factor from another table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of all parts, then you can do:

```
select p.part, nz(l.cnt, 0) + nz(r.cnt, 0)
from (parts as p left join
      (select leftpart, count(*) as cnt
       from table t
       group by leftpart
      ) as l
      on p.part = l.leftpart
     ) left join
     (select rightpart, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      group by rightpart
     ) as r
     on p.part = r.rightpart;
```

If you don't have such a table, you can create a view from a query:

```
select leftpart
from table
union
select rightpart
from table;
```

And then use the view in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
Select
    BothParts, Sum(BothQty) As TotalQuantity
From

(Select 
    [Left Part] As BothParts, [Left Part Qty] As BothQty
From
    YourTable
Union All
Select
    [Right Part] As BothParts, [Right Part Qty] As BothQty
From
    YourTable) As T

Group By BothParts;
```